# SQL Server : Islands And Gaps

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm struggling with an "Islands and Gaps" issue. This is for SQL Server 2008 / 2012 (we have databases on both).

I have a table which tracks "available" Serial-#'s for a Pass Outlet; i.e., Buss Passes, Admissions Tickets, Disneyland Tickets, etc. Those Serial-#'s are `VARCHAR`, and can be any combination of numbers and characters... any length, up to the max value of the defined column... which is `VARCHAR(30)`. And this is where I'm mightily struggling with the syntax/design of a VIEW.

The table (`IM_SER`) which contains all this data has a primary key consisting of:

```
ITEM_NO...VARCHAR(20),  
SERIAL_NO...VARCHAR(30)
```

In many cases... particularly with different types of the "Bus Passes" involved, those Serial-#'s could easily track into the TENS of THOUSANDS. What is needed... is a simple view in SQL Server... which simply outputs the CONSECUTIVE RANGES of Available Serial-#'s...until a GAP is found (i.e. a BREAK in the sequences).  For example, say we have the following Serial-#'s on hand, for a given Item-#:

```
123  
124  
125  
139  
140  
ABC123  
ABC124  
ABC126   
XYZ240003  
XYY240004
```

In my example above, the output would be displayed as follows:

```
123  -to-  125  
139  -to-  140  
ABC123  -to-  ABC124  
ABC126  -to-  ABC126  
XYZ240003  to  XYZ240004
```

In total, there would be 10 Serial-#'s...but since we're outputting the *sequential ranges*...only 5-lines of output would be necessary.  Does this make sense?  Please let me know...and, again, THANK YOU!...Mark

Comment: The varying format of the serial numbers is going to be a bit of an issue. How would you expect to handle ABC1244 in your example?

Comment: Can you split your number into 2 parts, the string part (empty, ABC or XYZ) + then the number? that way you can handle the fields separately and do the needed gaps & islands calculations for the number.

Comment: Hi TheMadDBA.  If we had a record, given the example above, with "ABCD1244", then we'd have to have SIX lines of output, because you'd be correct, in that it would NOT fall into a sequential range.

Hi JamesZ.  I don't have any clue how to do this.  That's why I need the syntax assistance :-)  Thanks!...Mark

Comment: Well, without the syntax, can you define & describe the logic of how you can reliably split the string so that you can sort strictly by the numerical portion?  In your post you say they can be ANY combination of numbers and characters.   What would happen with "A1A" and "A1B"?

Comment: Hi Tab Allerman...I see your point.  OK...so to finetune my logic...these Serial-#'s would either be in the format of "######" (strictly numeric only), "XXXXX" (strictly Alpha Only), "###XXX" (numeric-then-alpha), or "XXX###" (alpha-then-numeric).  We would not have an Alpha-Numeric-Alpha situation, my bad on that, sorry.

Comment: So is it safe to assume you can use length of the serial number and whether it is alpha-number,alpha or numeric as the first stage of the "grouping"?

Comment: Hi TheMadDBA...yes, I would agree with that logic.  Thus, a small test/comparison...of the "length" of the unique Serial-# in question, would have to be compared (I'm guessing on this) to the prior Serial-#...and IF is was the same length as the prior, only then could it qualify as a part of THAT particular range.  There could, of course, therefore, be LOTS of "ranges"...within the same Item-#...based on the logic above.  Does that make sense?  Please let me know...Thanks!...Mark

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started... the fun part will be determining if there are gaps or not. You will have to handle each serial format a little bit differently to determine if there are gaps or not...

```
select x.item_no,x.s_format,x.s_length,x.serial_no,
LAG(x.serial_no) OVER (PARTITION BY x.item_no,x.s_format,x.s_length 
 ORDER BY x.item_no,x.s_format,x.s_length,x.serial_no) PreviousValue,
LEAD(x.serial_no) OVER (PARTITION BY x.item_no,x.s_format,x.s_length 
 ORDER BY x.item_no,x.s_format,x.s_length,x.serial_no) NextValue
from 
(
 select item_no,serial_no,
 len(serial_no) as S_LENGTH,
 case
 WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',serial_no) > 0 AND
      PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',serial_no) = 0 THEN 'NUMERIC'
 WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',serial_no) > 0 AND
      PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',serial_no) > 0 THEN 'ALPHANUMERIC'
 ELSE 'ALPHA'     
 end as S_FORMAT
 from table1 ) x
 order by item_no,s_format,s_length,serial_no
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5636e2/7

```
| item_no |     s_format | s_length | serial_no | PreviousValue | NextValue |
|---------|--------------|----------|-----------|---------------|-----------|
|       1 |        ALPHA |        4 |      ABCD |        (null) |      ABCF |
|       1 |        ALPHA |        4 |      ABCF |          ABCD |    (null) |
|       1 | ALPHANUMERIC |        6 |    ABC123 |        (null) |    ABC124 |
|       1 | ALPHANUMERIC |        6 |    ABC124 |        ABC123 |    ABC126 |
|       1 | ALPHANUMERIC |        6 |    ABC126 |        ABC124 |    (null) |
|       1 | ALPHANUMERIC |        9 | XYY240004 |        (null) | XYZ240003 |
|       1 | ALPHANUMERIC |        9 | XYZ240003 |     XYY240004 |    (null) |
|       1 |      NUMERIC |        3 |       123 |        (null) |       124 |
|       1 |      NUMERIC |        3 |       124 |           123 |       125 |
|       1 |      NUMERIC |        3 |       125 |           124 |       139 |
|       1 |      NUMERIC |        3 |       139 |           125 |       140 |
|       1 |      NUMERIC |        3 |       140 |           139 |    (null) |
```

Comment: Hi TheMadDBA.  OK, so I reviewed your code, and altered it slightly, such that the Serial-#'s are all "in sequence", as follows:

order by item_no,s_format,s_length,serial_no

Now, using your SQLFiddle, they are all "in sequence" so to speak, and that's good.

What I don't understand is, what would be the syntax, for outputting this, in "ranges"?  Is there some type of grouping that could be done here, or am I missing the boat?  Please let me know...I'm confused...Thanks!...Mark

Comment: Well I don't have the time to write everything for you but... you would have to add logic to determine if a serial number is in sequence or not and output another column(using the previous and next value columns to compare to). Then you can wrap another select around that to filter and or group by as needed.